# ThreaInfo.getLockedMonitors() list the below stack trace in swing application

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

Could some one help when using a webstart application, i am facing this issue, i am using pack200

STACK TRACE:

```
java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.readAndMaybeSaveStreamTo(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.authenticateJarEntry(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.EnhancedJarVerifier.validate(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$3.run(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$3.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.getJarSigningData(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getSigningData(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile$JarFileEntry.getCodeSigners(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getCodeSigners(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) 2) That stack trace seems to be missing the first line. 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Comment: I printed the stack information from:                                    `code`StackTraceElement[] stackElements = threadInfo.getStackTrace();
for (StackTraceElement stackElement :stackElements) {
  sb.append(stackElement.toString());
}`code`

Comment: Need help to resolve this.  Which problem make this to print.                       I used to print this stack trace in a scheduled rate of time to check any lock present in application.

Comment: Can we get rid of this                                                                     
   STACK TRACE:    java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: Don't post the stack trace in a comment. Instead [edit] the question.